# NGINX serve static file for all sub-routes

Tags: nginx, url-routing

I am hosting two "versions" of UI for my app. I have the following routes configured on my nginx conf file:

```
  location /v2 {
    auth_request /auth
    try_files '' /frontendv2/app/index.html =404;
  }

  location / {
    auth_request /auth
    root /frontend/app;
    index index.html;
  }
```

`v1` is a single route app (no deep links, supports slugs only - eg: `example.com/`, `example.com/#members`, `example.com/#tasks`) and `v2` is also a single page app but which can have sub-routes (`/v2`, `/v2/members`, `/v2/tasks`, `/v2/tasks/<taskID>` etc).

My `v1` works fine but all the links for `v2` throw 404 error. I want all routes for `v2` to serve statically from `/frontendv2/app/index.html`

Comment: Try change `try_files '' /fronttendv2/app/index.html =404;` to `root /fontend/app; try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html?$args;`

Comment: You configuration file is missing two `;` characters, and a `root` or `alias` statement for the `location /v2` block. Your `try_files` statement makes no sense - what is `''` supposed to do?.